# Excel VBA keeps returning formula with "@" when referencing sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel VBA script that does an index/match across two separate sheets. The issue I'm facing is that it codes the formula in my spreadsheet using `"@"` and it doesn't end up picking the values. I have to go in and manually delete the `@` sign so that the formula works.

Does anyone have any suggestion how I can remove the `@` symbol?

Code below:

```
 lws.Range(lRangeAddress).Formula = "=INDEX('" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$C$2:$C$10000,MATCH(1,($F4='" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$B$2:$B$10000)*($G4='" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$A$2:$A$10000),0))"
```

The formula it returns:

```
=INDEX('Lever 2Query2'!$C$2:$C$10000,MATCH(1,($F5=@'Lever 2Query2'!$B$2:$B$10000)*($G5=@'Lever 2Query2'!$A$2:$A$10000),0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Formula2`, please:

```
lws.Range(lRangeAddress).Formula2 = "=INDEX('" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$C$2:$C$10000,MATCH(1,($F4='" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$B$2:$B$10000)*($G4='" _
                        & qwsName & "'!$A$2:$A$10000),0))"
```